# xtext prase of context dependant grammars

Tags: xtext

I have the grammar

```
Model:
    vars+=Vars*
    funcs+=Funcs*;

Name:
    name=ID;

VarName:
    Name;

FuncName:
    Name;

Funcs:
    'func' left=FuncName (bracket?='(' ')')? '=' right=[Name]';';

Vars:
    'var' VarName ';';
```

where the right hand size of the `Func` rule can be either of type `VarName` or `FuncName` depending is the brackets on the left hand size appear.

Must I modify the xtext grammar or do a type of validation/scoping?

**Update 1**

the scope function:

```
override getScope(EObject context, EReference reference) {
    if (context instanceof Funcs) {
        val func = context as Funcs
        if (reference == MultiNameDslPackage.Literals.FUNCS__RIGHT) {
            if (func.bracket) {
                val rootElement = EcoreUtil2.getRootContainer(context)
                val candidates = EcoreUtil2.getAllContentsOfType(rootElement, VarName)
                return Scopes.scopeFor(candidates)
            } else {
                val rootElement = EcoreUtil2.getRootContainer(context)
                val candidates = EcoreUtil2.getAllContentsOfType(rootElement, FuncName)
                return Scopes.scopeFor(candidates)
            }
        }
        return super.getScope(context, reference);
    }
}
```

The left hand size is independent of the presence of the brackets in the editor.

**Update 2**

Using validation

```
@Check
def checkFuncContext(Funcs func) {
    if (func.bracket) {
        if (!(func.right instanceof VarName)) {
            warning("Right hand size must be of Var type", 
                MultiNameDslPackage.Literals.FUNCS__RIGHT
            )
        }
    } else {
        if (!(func.right instanceof FuncName)) {
            warning("Right hand size must be of Function type", 
                MultiNameDslPackage.Literals.FUNCS__RIGHT
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The warning statements are not executed. The statement `func.right instanceof FuncName)` does not behave as expected.

How can I test for the correct instance?

**Update 3**

Using a modified grammar

```
VarName:
    name=ID;

FuncName:
    name=ID;

Funcs:
    'func' left=FuncName (bracket?='(' ')')? '=' (right=[FuncName] | r1=[VarName]) ';';
```

does not compile: `Decision can match input such as "RULE_ID" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2`

Comment: Simply implement a scopeprovider does not work?

Comment: See the updated question. Is the scope provider the correct place the do the validation? In the larger grammar the context needs to assist in the correct selection of a parse path.

Comment: It is one possible location. The other would be validator since it may give you better error messages

Comment: I tried validation also but as with the scope function the results is not as expected.

Comment: In which respect ? What's not working as expected in both cases?

Comment: BTW your grammar is bogus I'd expect Name:FuncName|varname; FuncName : name=ID;...

Comment: If the left hand side have brackets the left hand side must have type VarName.

Comment: Rule `Name` and inheritance was used to get the grammar to compile. It does look if I want to add too much semantic information in the xtext grammar.

Comment: No you simply got the inheritance false . You need Parent:Child1|Child2; you made name a child of parent1 and parent 2. if you want to reuse grammar parts you need fragments fragment Name:name=ID;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your grammar to get the inheritance order for Name, FuncName and VarName right (Name super type of both)

Either use a parser fragment

```
fragment Name: name=ID;
```

Or use

```
Name:VarName|FuncName;
VarName: name=ID;
FuncName:name=ID;
```